# HTTP URL Encoded Request failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, lamp, url-encoding

I have an application written in PHP using Codeigniter sitting on a LAMP stack.  Our tester has a very strange error that I am unable to replicate on any other machine.  Whenever she sends a request to the test server that contains a space (and I assume any other characters that need encoding) the request just hangs and never gets a response.  The same request to the live server works fine. The same request to the test server from any other machine also works fine.  So I thought that perhaps there was a problem with the charset used in the request or the response.  I have checked the default charset in Apache and PHP and they are both set to 'UTF-8'.  Any suggestions/thoughts/pointers? I have a feeling I am missing something simple which is just escaping me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was... Although I do not know or fully understand why it would occur.  The tester was the only machine using the proxy server on the network.  I removed the use of the proxy and everything works fine...